# MySQL, C#, You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, syntax

I don't know what is wrong in this code:

**C#**:

```
string myConnection1 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "UPDATE private IF p1c='0' THEN SET p1c='1' where Eid='123456789' ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(myConnection1);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader1;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader1 = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Every time I got error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; chceck the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF p1c='0' THEN SET p1c='1' where Eid='123456789" at line 1"

Maybe is problem with "**IF**" and "**THEN**"?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `if`, it could be in the where

```
UPDATE private 
set  p1c='1' where Eid='123456789' and p1c='0';
```